# Iterating List in Map and create new map in java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to implement below code in Stream in java8.  Not getting right implementation in stream. Is it possible to optimize below code using stream

```
MySampleObject
    field1;
    field2;
```

```
 Map<String, List<MySampleObject>>  dbMap = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, String>  finalMap = new HashMap<>(); 
            for (Entry<String, List<MySampleObject>> mapid : dbMap.entrySet()) {
                List<MySampleObject> sampleList = mapid.getValue();
                for(MySampleObject obj : sampleList) {
                    try { 
                        if (null != obj.getField1() ) {
                            finalMap.put(obj.getField1+"_"+obj.getField2, obj.getField1());
                        } else {
                            ..
                        }   
                         
                    } catch ( Exception e) { 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: While the Stream API is suitable for straight-forwardly creating a `Map` like that, it has no equivalent to `else { .. }` (whatever that is) or `catch ( Exception e) {}`. Of course, the latter is problematic anyway, whether you use the Stream API or not. It’s also unclear why it’s even there. Maybe it’s related to the `else { .. }` part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flatMap function like

```
dbMap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).forEach(obj -> {
  try {
    if (null != obj.getField1()) {
      finalMap.put(obj.getField1() + "_" + obj.getField2(), obj.getField1());
    } else {
       ..
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
});
```